# Zend Framework translate language text

Tags: zend-framework

I have some translation code which is working fine.

```
<?php echo $this->translate("54"); ?>
```

Outputs

```
Hello World
```

is it possible to output instead of above

```
<div class='lang' id='54'>Hello World</div>
```

Later using jquery I would like to manipulate the div.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom view helper named `MyTranslate extends \Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate` then override the _invoke method :

```
public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = null, $locale = null)
{
    $t = parent::__invoke($message, $textDomain , $locale);
    //change the value of $t however you wnat
    return $t;
}
```

if you don't what to change your code where ever you have used `translate` register this new view helper as `translate` and not `my_translate`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Zend1, you can use a view helper like this:

1. Create a `Helper` directory in your library
   for example, in my case I have this directory:
   library/DoyDoy/Helper/
2. Create your helper like this:
   library/DoyDoy/Helper/**TranslateID.php**

   ```
   <?php
    class DoyDoy_Helper_TranslateID extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
   {
       public function translateID($id)
       {
           return '<div class=\'lang\' id=\'' . $id . '\'>'. $this->view->translate($id) . '</div>';
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add your Helper in the bootstrap:

   ```
   protected function _initDoyDoyView(){
       $this->bootstrap('view');
       $view = $this->getResource('view');
       $view->addHelperPath('DoyDoy/Helper/', 'DoyDoy_Helper');        
   }
   ```
4. In your view, call the helper like this:

   ```
   <?php echo $this->translateID("54");?>
   ```

   This should display:

   ```
   <div class='lang' id='54'>Hello World</div>
   ```

I hope it will help you :)